# Why aren't my native libraries copied into the apk?

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to build an android application with a few native libraries. NDK builds the libraries successfully, and I can see them in `...\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a\src\<library>\lib<library>.a`

But when I run the app I get an unsatisfied link error and when I analyze the APK, the native libraries are nowhere to be found; only libc++_shared.so.
Here's the relevant portion of the app's build.gradle:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        version "3.10.2"
        path "../../../CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DENABLE_QT=0", // Don't use QT
                    "-DENABLE_SDL2=0", // Don't use SDL
                    "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=true", // cryptopp requires Neon to work
                    "-DENABLE_CUBEB=0",
                    "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"

            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'

            targets "citra-android"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about [this repository](https://github.com/BreadFish64/citra/), then, your issue lies in `src/android/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(citra-android STATIC
        dummy.cpp
        )
```

You are supposed to use `SHARED` instead of `STATIC` for Gradle to generate a shared object file (`.so`) instead of a `.a` file.

Hope it helps, thanks.